# Docker run vs Podman run

Tags: docker, podman

I have got the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.6.0-alpine3.15
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual .builds-deps build-base python3 python3-dev py3-pip && \
    echo "echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add linux-headers && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install RPi.GPIO rpi_ws281x adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install && mkdir -p backend/images
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

This container image is running on a raspberry pi and I am controlling for example a led stripe.

The weird thing is that everything works with this docker run command:

```
docker run --rm --name cm_back_test --privileged -e CM_USER=superuser -e CM_PASSWORD=superuser -e CM_CLUSTER=cluster.xxxx.mongodb.net cm-back:1.0.0
```

I need the privileged flag for the gpio stuff.
But for some reasone the exact same command with podman does not work.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: just to check - you are running your podman installation in privleged mode rather than the normal unprivileged mode?

Comment: I use podman with the standard user and don’t start podman containers/pods via sudo

Comment: if podman is running as your normal user then "--privileged" isn't going to give the container any permissions you don't already have. It just locks it down less than it normally would. You will need to run the container as root if it is going to need root permissions for GPIO stuff